# Problema na instalação do AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Estou com problema para instalar o AngularJs, mas tenho quase certeza que o que esta errado é o caminho do `src` e onde coloco os arquivos do angular (em qual pasta).

Se possível, informe;

1. Quais os arquivos do Angular eu preciso?
2. Em qual pasta eu coloco os arquivos do angular?
3. Qual é o caminho que descrevo no `src`?

Comment: Qual versão do Angular você está tenta do usar?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é ler o [Guia de Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Answer (score 2):

O único arquivo necessário é o `angular.js` ou o `angular.min.js`. Se você estiver usando o arquivo do CDN ficará assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
```

Se você estiver usando o arquivo que baixou da [página oficial](https://angularjs.org/) você precisa coloca-lo em algum local onde seja possível acessá-lo externamente. Digamos que você coloque na raiz do seu projeto, então a importação ficará assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./angular.js"></script>
```